# Datasnap / dbExpress deployment issues

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap, dbexpress

I'm playing around with setting up a Datasnap server on IIS at the moment.

I have managed to get the default Datasnap / Javascript demo to work, and have extended it to include my own string based results to a version of the webpage.

However I am being stumped moving to the next level.

I want to add in a database module and return results from a MySQL database accessed via dbExpress.

As soon as I add a datamodule with a TSQLConnection and TSQLQuery on it and roll out the compiled dll the server stops working.  Remove the Datamodule and recompile and everything is fine.

I've tried adding the libmysql.dll and dbxmysql.dll to the website root and adding them to the ISAPI restriction list to allow them to run, but I'm obviously missing something else.

**Update**
Following some more testing the core issue is with adding an extra datamodule for the TSQLConnection & TSQLQuery.  If I include these on the TServerMethods1 unit then the app works...

Comment: I think midas.dll needs also be deployed. Did you? Or alternatively, add MidasLib in uses clause of project file. That way it is statically linked.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, insert **MidasLib** in your USES clause, better than deploying another dll, this will keep everything you need in your executable.

Comment: Adding Midas to the project source does not solve the issue. Adding a DataModule causes the Application Pool to stop. Having everything on ServerMethods1 causes everything to work...

Comment: Well, adding Midas to the "project source" is another thing. I mentioned "insert MidasLib in your USES clause", that means in your DataModule: uses MidasLib, Windows, ...